# How to Apply slideToggle functionality to jquery insertAfter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with dynamic rows like

```
<table>
 for(int i=0;i<=Modal.Count;i++)
  {
    <tr class="trList">
    <td class="tdEmpid><input type="button" value="Insert row"  class="btnInsert"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Sun_Hrs' + i + '"   value="' + data.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SUN_HRS + '" style = "width:50px;border: 0px;background-color: white;text-align: left;" readonly="true"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Mon_Hrs' + i + '"   value="' + data.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].MON_HRS + '" style = "width:50px;border: 0px;background-color: white;text-align: left;" readonly="true"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Tue_Hrs' + i + '"   value="' + data.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].TUE_HRS + '" style = "width:50px;border: 0px;background-color: white;text-align: left;" readonly="true"/></td>;
        ..........
        ..........                                                                
    </tr>
   }
```

Now, I want to add row where the button dynamically exactly to next row where button is clicked , for that i have written jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnInsert').live('click',function(){
        var html = '<tr class="trNeedTimesheet"><td></td><td></td></td><td><p style="background-color:white;">--  Need To Enter TImesheetHours</b> -------</p></td></tr>';
        $("" + html + "").insertAfter($(this).parent('td.tdEmpId').parent('tr.trList')); 
    });
 });
```

It is not only adding , but it should insert and  work same like slidetoggle functionality.
How can I do that?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been long deprecated (jQuery 1.7) and removed (1.9).

Comment: "var html" has big stuff, i have used that for sample to show.

Comment: 1. line 5 `<td class="tdEmpid>` should be `<td class="tdEmpid">`. 2. First `<td>` does not have `</td>` tag

Comment: Please ignore it, now i edited,how can i do same slideToggle functionality for above, any suggestions

Comment: @sanjay, add my working fiddle to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) don't accept argument but [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) do.

Change this line

```
$("" + html + "").insertAfter($(this).parent('td.tdEmpId').parent('tr.trList'));
```

to

```
$("" + html + "").insertAfter($(this).parents('tr.trList'));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/341/)**

**Edit** : updated toggle functionality.

jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click','.btnInsert', function(){
    var $nextTr =  $(this).parents('tr.trList').next();
    var newTrExist =$nextTr.hasClass('newTr');
 if(newTrExist)
 {
   $nextTr.toggle();  
 }
 else
 {      
       var html = '<tr class="newTr trNeedTimesheet"><td></td><td></td></td><td><p style="background-color:white;">--  Need To Enter TImesheetHours</b> -------</p></td></tr>';
       $(html).insertAfter($(this).parents('tr.trList'));
 }
```

});

Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/345/) :

Comment: That's ok , How can i apply like slide toggle;

Comment: slidetoggle to button?

Comment: Yes, I have used insertAfter() to insert exactly next to button on click, but it should hide and show like slide.

Comment: in your Demo is adding rows is ok, but when i click again it should hide the row

Comment: see update.. here I am adding new class newTr to each newly added tr so that I can identify the added tr.

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Saku7/3/)**

For insert **[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**,

```
$(html).insertAfter($(this).parents('tr.trList'));
```

For **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**,

```
$(document).on('click','.trNeedTimesheet',function(){
   $('p',this).slideToggle()
});
```

Comment: thanks..! but slide functionality need to apply only for button 'btnInsert'

Comment: okay, now the question seems clear.Wait, do you want to hide the new row or remove ?